# How to pass build number from which artifacts are copied using CopyArtifact plugins for Pipeline Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

How to pass build number from which artifacts are copied in Pipeline Job?
Because default this step copy artifacts from last stable build and I need copy artifacts from specific build (e.g. 123).

My pipeline code is here:

```
node {
  stage "Copy artifacts"
  step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
          projectName: 'other-project',
          filter: 'myapp.jar']);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From official blog [post](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/copying-artifacts-between-builds-jenkins-workflow):

> All other config options that the copyartifact-plugin supports are
>   also available. The easiest way to test/browse all options is through
>   the Workflow script “Snippet Generator” (available on the workflow
>   configuration screen below the workflow script textarea).

If it could be parameterized, appropriate option should be available in built-in "Snippet Generator" .

To copy artifact from specific build, you need to additionally use `selector` parameter:

```
node {
  stage "Copy artifacts"
  step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
          projectName: 'other-project',
          filter: 'myapp.jar', 
          selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: '1']
        ]);
}
```

Comment: When I open snippet generator I haven't option Copy Artifact. This is the reason why I asked this question. I use Jenkins 2.0 and Copy Artifact Plugin 1.38. For other tools like ansible snippet generator works, but I haven't snippet generator for this plugin.

Comment: You are right. For some reason Snippet Generator in Jenkins 2.0 does not include `step` for `CopyArtifact`. The only way to get proper parameters is to either use Jenkins < 2.0 or check plug-in's [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/copyartifact).

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such problem. If you can, please file a bug with detailed steps.

Comment: @JesseGlick Initially I've tested with Jenkins `2.0-beta-1`, but after upgrading to `2.0` `CopyArtifact` step is available. I suspect I might have been some minor glitch or my misconfiguration.

Comment: I'm on 2.44 and don't see CopyArtifact in snippet generator